# SUM function in PIG

Tags: apache-pig, apache-pig-grunt

Starting to learn Pig latin scripting and stuck on below issue. I have gone through similar questions on the same topic without any luck! Want to find SUM of all the age fields.

```
  DUMP X;
(22)(19)
grunt> DESCRIBE X;
X: {age: int}
```

I tried several options such as :

```
Y = FOREACH ( group X all ) GENERATE SUM(X.age);
```

But, getting below exception.

```
 Invalid field projection. Projected field [age] does not exist in schema: group:chararray,X:bag{:tuple(age:int)}.
```

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: post your script as well. what you are trying to do?

Comment: Sample Data;
(smith,{(raptors, 1),(leafs, 2)}, [age#22])
(carol,{(yankees, 1),(blue jays, 2), (cavaliers, 3)}, [age#19])

Script Code:
 A = LOAD 'input/pigData/pig_expressions.txt' AS T: tuple(f1:chararray, f2:bag {T2:tuple(t1:chararray, t2:int)}, f3:map[]);
 
X = FOREACH A GENERATE T.f3#'age' AS age:int;

Comment: You can edit your question and post these steps in question itself. Someone might help here.

Comment: can you try X.$0.age

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the Y projection should work as you wrote it. Here's mi little example code for the same and that's just work fine for me.

```
 X = LOAD 'SO/sum_age.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (age:int);
 DESCRIBE X;
 Y = FOREACH ( group X all ) GENERATE 
     SUM(X.age);
 DESCRIBE Y;
 DUMP Y;
```

So you your problem looks strange. I used the following input data:

```
-bash-4.1$ cat sum_age.txt 
22
19
```

Can you make a try on the same data with script I inserted here?

Comment: Thanks for your time and help. The example you provided does work. However, no luck with the data that I have got.

Comment: Can you share some example of the input data you have?

Comment: (smith,{(raptors, 1),(leafs, 2)}, [age#22])

Comment: (carol,{(yankees, 1),(blue jays, 2), (cavaliers, 3)}, [age#19])

Comment: Do you have the pig schema file for this?

Comment: I have these statements from the grunt shell:
A = LOAD 'input/pigData/pig_expressions.txt' AS T: tuple(f1:chararray, f2:bag {T2:tuple(t1:chararray, t2:int)}, f3:map[]);
X = FOREACH A GENERATE T.f3#'age' AS age:int;
Y = FOREACH ( group X all ) GENERATE SUM(X.age);

Comment: I'll check it for you this week

Comment: Ok here's the answer, (I get the idea from my colleague; Thanks Jon!) You need to cast the map value explicitly:                                                            X = FOREACH A GENERATE (int)T.f3#'age' AS age;                                       This solves your issue.

Comment: Thank you and Jon for your consistent help.